# Import built from source libraries to pycharm IDE

Tags: python, windows, cmake, pycharm

after having built a library with cmake and visual studio, does anyone knows what to do to successfully import this build library by Pycharm on windows, like which paths should we add to system variables ... I know that some tutorials clearly explain the building phase but they, unfortunately, do not describe in detail how to integrate this to your IDE

Comment: https://cv-tricks.com/how-to/installation-of-opencv-4-1-0-in-windows-10-from-source/
I followed this Tutorial and many others

Comment: Please describe the steps you took to try to load OpenCV into Pycharm in detail, and please provide the **full** error message in your question post.

Comment: after I built the library I  set OpenCV bin to system PATH (pycharm didn't detect it)
the error is:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' everytime I try to import cv2

Comment: Do not use *comments* for provide information about the problem. Instead, [edit] the **question post**.